# Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector

Tags: python, kotlin, yolo

I have best.pt but i don't understand how i can use this in android kotlin.
my model was generated for a mobile application according to the documentation from yolo8, but I get an error when I access the model from the code

Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Mobile SSD models are expected to have exactly 4 outputs, found 2

I looked for solutions on the Internet, but could not come up with a result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.